# Realtime database get name and value

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am using firebase real-time database.

there is the user name like - user1 and then some supplies he requested like the supplies name - markers and then the quantity - like 5.

this is my JSON file

```
    {
  "Users" : {
    "User1" : {
      "Markers" : 5,
      "Scissors" : 1,
      "Staplers" : 4
    },
        "User2" : {
      "Markers" : 2,
      "Scissors" : 5,
      "Staplers" : 3
    }
  }
}
```

i want to get back the supplies whan i ask for in the format of:

markers 5

scissors 1

Staplers 4

the information comes out via a listview but i don't know how to get via the listview both name and quantity, i can get only one of them.

The code i am using to get only the names is:

```
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
            }
```

and the code i am using to get only the quantity is:

```
// two first lines are the same
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getValue().toString());
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have changed the script to this one

```
            key = (((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
            value = ((dataSnapshot).child(key).getValue().toString());
            set.add(key+" "+value);
```

it works very good, thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
for (DataSnapshot supply : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String key = supply.getKey();
    String value = supply.getValue();
}
```

Also, you could have just saved `i.next()` to a variable, then you can access the `key` and `value` within the same loop without calling additional `i.next()` (which I presume is what the question is about).